# Why I can connect to remote server, but not to server in local network?

Tags: android, networking

I implemented a TCP client and it's working fine so far, at least if I try to connect to a REMOTE server. If that server is in my LOCAL wifi network, I always get

```
02-20 14:09:04.400: W/System.err(29562): java.net.SocketException: failed to connect to /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (port xyz) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
```

BUT!! if I have the LOCAL server ping my android device, after it got pinged it will work and the device will connect to my LOCAL server.

Any known reasons for this behaviour? I have no clue where I should start looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't done any discovery yet of the local network so the device doesn't know where the server is situated. The answer lies in the error:
"No route to host"

Do a discovery of the network to update the MAC table first. Normally you can check if the MAC is already known (in the ARP table) if not, do an ARP request first.

Reason why it works when you first ping from the server: the MAC is then known by the mobile device (in the ARP table or MAC table).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sounds perfectly reasonable for a network noob like me. Is Using Network Service Discovery http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html#discover the way to go?

Comment: The description says it will listen to services that broadcast on the network. This if fine if you just want to know what is broadcasting. Here is a socket programming tutorial for andriod: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/